# Multiple URL Calls in UIWebView

Tags: uitableview, ios6, uiwebview, xcode4.5, master-detail

I have a **master/detail** view app that I am currently building. Basically it has a list in a table for the master view, when the user selects an item, it will display a web page in a `UIWebView` in the detail view.
There will be about 6 different websites that will needed to be loaded in response to the 6 objects in the table. I have the code working to a point, however it is loading the same web page for each item in the table. I thought it would be best to write a switch case statement to tell it which web page to load etc. I have used the following code to launch my web page in the `WebView`:

```
//create the UIWeb objects
NSString *standardForm = @"http://jeremy.atkin.id.au";
NSString *csiroForm = @"http://www.csiro.gov.au";
NSString *kpmgForm = @"http://www.kpmg.com.au";
NSString *pacbrandsForm = @"http://www.pacbrands.com.au";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:standardForm];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_formView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

I then tried to put together the switch case statement, but seem to by making the wrong declarations and constantly get errors...

```
switch (_formNumber)
{
    case 0:
        standardForm.url = standardForm;
        break;
    case 2:
        url.URLWithString = csiroForm;
        break;
    case 3:
        url.URLWithString = kpmgForm;
        break;
    case 4:
        url.URLWithString = pacbrandsForm;
        break;
}
```

Any help and direction to get this working correctly would be greatly appreciated. I have never built a **master/detail** app before so I am thinking I jumped straight in the deep end!!
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the links to one NSArray , then create url based on the tableviewCell selected index and load your webview with the request.

1)Create a property for urlList in master

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *urlList;
```

Then synthesis in implementation.

```
@synthesize urlList;
```

2)In your init or viewDidLoad initialize the array

```
self.urlList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"http://jeremy.atkin.id.au",@"http://www.csiro.gov.au", @"http://www.kpmg.com.au",@"http://www.pacbrands.com.au",nil];
```

3)On didSelectRowAtIndexPath:index create the request and load your web view.

```
NSURLRequest * request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[urlList objectAtIndex:indexPath]]];
[_formView loadRequest:request];
```

Don't forget to release (retained object) in dealloc .If using arc then change retain in property to strong.

Comment: - (void)stopLoading call this before loading new request.

Comment: very nice, appreciate your help above! very informative. I started this app as a single page view, as with most of mine and constructed my own navigation controller, which does not necessarily conform as above. Would it have been best to use the master/detail template to start off?

Comment: Yes. You can watch (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nrj7VGKdCOs) Stanford video tutorial. After watching I am confident that you'll be able to implement master detail easily without anyone's help. Are you creating an universal application (iPhone,iPod and iPad) or just iPhone?

Comment: Awesome, I will check out the video... Master/Detail has always been one of my challenges... Thanks once again for your assistance, most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to just change the URL in UITableView Didselectmethod.